# Are just plain sudokus allowed?

Tags: discussion

Is it okay for questions to have just plain sudokus? Or do they have to have a element in them?

Because, I don't see any posts with just plain sudokus, but are they allowed?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As long as the puzzle is either

1. your own or
2. properly attributed,

there are no *rules against* posting just a plain sudoku. (In fact, [here's an example](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/93821).)

That being said, it would likely not be well-received.  Users of this site aren't here looking for sudokus; there are many sites out there that provide as many sudokus as anyone could want.  This site is more about the *creation and solving* of puzzles.

Thus people have posted questions asking

- how to get [past a certain point](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/102426) in a sudoku that has them stumped.
- how to [create a sudoku with specific features](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/614)
- if it is possible to [make an "unsolvable" sudoku](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/12)
- how to [test a sudoku solver](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98781)

So the TLDR is that it's not off-topic, but probably won't be well-received.

Comment: To point out one thing about the linked "here's an example" sudoku by athin that might not be noticed immediately - this was still not your bog-standard sudoku, as athin had cleverly crafted the puzzle so that the starting clues actually spelled out 'PSE' in the grid, a really nice artistic touch :) I agree with everything you say here, and echo your remark: "Users of this site aren't here looking for sudokus" - as you say, a sudoku with a little artistry about it (like the linked example) is definitely more this community's cup of tea :)